# getopts is not capturing arguments (file rename script)

Tags: bash, shell, sh, getopt, getopts

Based on [Google's Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml?showone=Case_statement#Case_statement), I made the following script. The script should take files like `a.txt` and `b.txt` and change them to `PREFIX_1_prefix_a.txt` and `PREFIX_1_prefix_b.txt`. However, when I enter:

```
$ sh rename_enum.sh -n 100 -P X -p Y
```

I expect `X_100_Y_a.txt` and `X_101_Y_b.txt`, but I get `_1_a.txt` and `_2_b.txt`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

#verbose='false'
nflag=1
Pflag=''
pflag='_'
files='*.txt'

while getopts 'nPpf' flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        n) nflag="${OPTARG}" ;;
        P) Pflag="${OPTARG}_" ;;
        p) pflag="_${OPTARG}_" ;;
        f) files="${OPTARG}" ;;
        #v) verbose='true' ;;
        *) error "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
    esac
done

for i in ${files}
do
    mv "$i" "${Pflag}${nflag}${pflag}$i"
    nflag=$((nflag + 1))
done
```

Comment: Start with `#!/bin/bash` when you use bash syntax. Use `for i in ${files}` and `${Pflag}${nflag}${pflag}$i` when following Googles style guide. Do not use backtics for command substition.

Comment: `expr ${OPTARG}` isn't actually doing anything. `nflag=$OPTARG` is sufficient.

Comment: Your handling of `files` is suboptimal. First, it will fail disastrously if a filename includes whitespace or a shell metacharacter. Second, you almost certainly want the interface to allow multiple files. I'd recommend deleting the `-f` option (and the variable files) and replacing the `for` statement with `for f in "${@:OPTIND}"; do`

Comment: @rici Thanks! I just realized that I was having problems because of that, and opened up my browser to search, and saw your comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this man page](http://ss64.com/bash/getopts.html) which explains that if a flag has an argument, then
it should be followed by a colon. All I had to do was change the line...

```
while getopts 'nPpf' flag; do
```

... to ...

```
while getopts 'n:P:p:f:' flag; do
```

... and I got the desired result. Thanks for the comments, though!